# In QuickBooks 2014, how to prepopulate MRU for all users?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-server-2012-r2, regedit, quickbooks

i have tried editing the registry and **QBWUSER.ini** file, but with no luck.  No matter what i have done to these two locations i have found filenames, when QBW 2014 is launched, the MRU does not change.

Registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QuickBooksCommon\QBFinder]
"0"="P:\\DOCS\\Quickbooks\\CarLights LLC  2015.QBW"
"1"="P:\\DOCS\\Quickbooks\\CarConsults LLC.QBW"
"2"="p:\\docs\\quickbooks\\Car Consultants.qbw"
```

INI File:
  "C:\Users\< username >\AppData\Local\Intuit\QuickBooks 2014\QBWUSER.INI"

```
[PREFS_STANDARD_STRATUM]
NEWUSER=N
AUTOBACKUPFREQUENCY=4
REPORTONFULLMONTHS=N
MULTIUSERMODE=N
MAXMRUFILES=6

[MRUFILES_STANDARD_STRATUM]
FILE1=P:\\DOCS\\Quickbooks\\CarLights LLC  2015.QBW
FILE2=P:\\DOCS\\Quickbooks\\CarConsults LLC.QBW
FILE3=P:\\DOCS\\Quickbooks\\Car Consultants.qbw
```

Answer (score 0):

After chopping down the QBWUSER.ini file for posting to SuperUser, i noticed the NEWUSER= option.  Changing NEWUSER=N to NEWUSER=Y AND running QuickBooks 2014 as Administrator seemed to force a reread of the MRU.

```
[PREFS_STANDARD_STRATUM]
NEWUSER=Y
```

Comment: There must be someway that the end user would not have to click "Runas Administrator" to get the ini to be fully reread.